# NSMutableArray with file path

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray of names of files in my app documents folder.
Now I want to make an array of file paths of those files which have names in the above array.
How am I gonna do this? I'm having trouble solving this and I couldnt think of any solutions. 
If you could help, I really appreciate it.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filename = [someArray objectAtIndex:i];
filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someImage" ofType:@"jpg"];
```